# Displaying Laravel Nova Resources several times with different conditions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I'm wondering if it is possible to display a Laravel Nova Resource twice.

For example, my resource is `Notification`

I would like to have a menu item notification that displays all the notifications but the `\App\Message` type, and another menu item `Messages` that would display only notifications that has notification type equals to `\App\Message`

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it can. maybe you can add another resource but with the same model and add a condition in indexQuery to display the message